# MobiOne/Jqtouch - SWIPE

Tags: jqtouch, mobione

I am not able to simulate the SWIPE event in MobiOne simulator while using Jqtouch.
How to use mouse to simulate swipe.

Thanks
Coool

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest MobiOne 1.0M9 version, it's iphone emulator supports JQTouch swipe events. Load this swipe demo URL http://www.ryanscherf.net/demos/swipe/ in the MobiOne iPhone Emulator. Press left-mouse down while dragging across the swipe regions. You should see an alert dialog with a msg stating you swiped left or right respectively. Use the MobiOne "Send To My Phone" to quickly share the URL with your iphone/itouch device and see it live.

Contact MobiOne Support for more followup. www.genuitec.com/support-mobione

Wayne